# Compile Kotlin and Java with Lombok using Gradle 5

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin, lombok

I am having issues compiling my code with Gradle 5.4.1.
Surprisingly, it started failing after updating to the latest version of IntelliJ and any attempt to return to a working version fail. I am however fairly certain that IntelliJ is not the problem.

The project is a mix of Java(legacy) and Kotlin code, using Lombok for the java code (legacy) as well as QueryDsl globally.

The Kotlin code compiles properly but the Java code fails.

I am posting my gradle build file where I removed most of the dependencies to simplify the reading as well as any bits that did not seem relevant.

```
plugins {
  id 'java'
  id 'idea'
  id 'com.chrisgahlert.gradle-dcompose-plugin' version '0.15.3' 
  id 'com.palantir.docker' version '0.22.1'
  id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.0.9.RELEASE'

  id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.jpa' version '1.3.41'
  id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.3.41'
  id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.spring' version '1.3.41'
  id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt' version '1.3.41'
  id 'io.spring.dependency-manageme' version '1.0.7.RELEASE'
}

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
  all {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.tomcat', module: 'tomcat-jdbc'
    exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
  }
}

compileJava {
  options.annotationProcessorPath = configurations.annotationProcessor
}


dependencies {
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'

  // QueryDSL
  compile("com.querydsl:querydsl-core:${queryDslVersion}")
  annotationProcessor("com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:${queryDslVersion}:jpa")
  implementation("com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:${queryDslVersion}")
  kapt  ("com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:${queryDslVersion}:jpa")

  // Lombok
  compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}"
  annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}"
  implementation("org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}")


  // Kotlin
  implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect'
  implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8'
  implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib'
  compile group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx', name: 'kotlinx-coroutines-core', version: '1.2.2'


}

sourceSets {
  main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/java'
  main.kotlin.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
}

compileKotlin {
  kotlinOptions {
    freeCompilerArgs = ['-Xjsr305=strict']
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
  }
}
```

I will typically get the following error (one of many) clearing indicating that getters/setters have not been generated.

```
model/entities/Client.java:71: error: cannot find symbol
      .filter(ex -> ex.getDateEnd() == null)
                      ^
  symbol:   method getDateEnd()
  location: variable ex of type Exercice
```

What am I missing / doing wrong ?
Is my only option to delombok ? (It would be extremely painful)

Thanks for your help.